# Searching for a Responsive Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am working on designing a site, which will be used both for desktops and mobile devices, and I am trying find a way of using a traditional drop-down menu, that could become better fitted in a mobile environment. (Something like an accordion or similar would be ideal)

Any and all suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: At least on the stock Android browser, a traditional `<select>` dropdown will show a scrollable list where you can select from, which has already an ok usability. You might confuse your mobile users if you decide to implement a custom dropdown.

Comment: iOS has a similar interface for selects as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for something that could transition a drop-down menu into something like an accordian, which retains the same functionality and is quite common on mobile devices, you may want to check the following link out: *(It is done purely using CSS)*

**[CSS Science | Responsive Dropdown to Accordian (With Demo)](http://csscience.com/dropdown-accordion/)**

*(This basically transitions your drop-down menu into an accordion when the browser width is less than 500, which should meet your needs for a "mobile" environment.)*

Comment: This is a pretty handy little CSS feature - It might be just what I need... Thanks!

Comment: i was also looking for it, great menu